# NSUserDefaults Inconsistency or device inconsistency? - iPhone

Tags: iphone

I have developed a server based app for iPhone. But according to client requirements and to avoid overloading on server side, **i am required to store data on local end. It is all text and typically 2-4 MB in size.**
For this i'm using **NSUserDefaults** instead of sqlite or CoreData.
The app has been tested successfully for around 2-3 months during it's development as well as post development testing and never shown any type of inconsistency in data storage, updation or deletion on any sort of iphone device from iphone 3G - iphone 4S.

Now there is an incosistency issue in the live app, **when user leave the app idle on a screen for around 15-20 minutes** and doesn't press home button means app is not in the background.
In this case, data seems to be lost.
But as soon as refresh app, in that case data appears again & app starts functioning normal again.
Here lies the main problem that **when i'm refreshing, i'm doing nothing but only fetching fresh data from the server it can be simply one to five records or nothing at all**.
Then app is refreshed, all of the records are shown & it functions normally.

I have been trying to spot the issue for around 3 days, and it's not happening on my device (iPhone 4S). As far as i can think, it seems to be problem with the old devices.

Previously in testing, none of this happened on old or new devices.
My questions are -

**a) Is this an incosistency in my coding?**

**b) Are NSUserDefaults not trustworthy for database management for live apps?**

**c) Is it a device version specific problem related to NSUserDefaults?**

Anybody faced/facing the problem with NSUserDefaults??

Please suggest me something i can do for this or tell me i have to do all the database work again for the next version using sqlite or CoreData.

Anyhow this is critically important and needs to be fixed.

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you're always calling synchronize on the NSUserDefaults?

Comment: Should i call synchronize in **appWillResignActive** and **appDidBecomeActive** methods or simply every time when i interact with NSUserDefaults throughout the app?                                                                Because right now i'm using synchronize with **UIApplicationDelegate** Methods.

Comment: Opinions vary; I always call it right after writing a value.

Comment: I think my work is done by calling it in **UIApplicationDelegate** methods  for now. **Thanks TomA** anyway for pointing out synchronize. I'm not sure about the problem has gone. But for now, my client is in peace at least...!

Answer (score 0):

As my suggestion for you please introduce the Sqlite database integration because of the when the short size of the data store and of cause it's good rather then the Sqlite but it's not working into large number of the data that time must use the Sqlite or coredata.

so i suggest to use the Sqlite data and coredata.